# Search-string inside a object/variable - Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-pipelines, azure-blob-storage

I have an object called `$latestBlob_content`, this contains logs from azure build pipeline. I want to find a specific string from this object. But when I call -  `$latestBlob_content | Select-String -Pattern $pattern` . This returns the whole logs. Is the 3rd line right way of reading a blob file!?

```
$blobs = Get-AzStorageBlob -Container $container_name -Context $context | sort @{Expression = "LastModified";Descending=$true}
$latestBlob = $blobs[0]
$latestBlob_content = $latestBlob.ICloudBlob.DownloadText()
$pattern = "Terraform_modules.azure_data_lake.*"
$latestBlob_content | Select-String -Pattern $pattern
```

Thanks in advance

Code those are not working -
 `$latestBlob_content.ToString() | Select-String -Pattern "Terraform_modules.azure_data_lake.*"`

Comment: `Select-String -InputObject $latestBlob_content -Pattern $pattern` also returns whole logs. no the specified pattern string

Comment: Try this command   `Select-String -Path .\*.txt -Pattern  'Terraform_modules.azure_data_lake.*'`

Comment: @RajkumarM , the blob is not in my drive. I am accessing it directly. I don't want to download the logs to my local drive

Comment: returns same result

Comment: Most likely, your `$latestBlob_content` is one string instead of an array of strings. You could check the type using `$latestBlob_content.GetType()`. If that is the case, you essentially pas 1 string to `Select-String` and ask it if the string contains your pattern and it does so it returns you back the complete string. You could try `$latestBlob_content -split "\`r?\`n" | Select-String -Pattern $pattern`

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers - you are totally right. Your solution WORKED. Thanks a lot. I was struggling for few days. Thank you so much!

Comment: For future reference, one of your first debugging steps should include the `.GetType()` method. I can't count the number of times I thought I was using an object of type A where it turned out to be type B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely, your `$latestBlob_content` is one string instead of an array of strings.You could check the type using `$latestBlob_content.GetType()`.

If that is the case, you are essentially passing one string to `Select-String` and ask it if the string contains your pattern. It does so it returns you back the complete string.

You could try following to split up your one string into an array of strings and select only those who match your pattern

```
$latestBlob_content -split "`r?`n" | Select-String -Pattern $pattern
```